# Changing directory ubuntu server script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, directory, command, cd

I´m working on a project and I have to use Ubuntu Server.

When I run

**"bash deploy.sh" or "./deploy.sh"** I´m not changing directory.

On my script I have

**cd ../..** so I can go up (twice), but it´s not working.

I have the same problem when I write the complete path

The error message is "*Directory or file does not exist*".

Do you know a cmd for changing directories?

Thank you in advanced!

Comment: The error clearly states that the directory does not exist, so you can't change directories until you give it a valid directory. What is the directory you are running the script in?

Answer (score 1):

this is because when you run:

```
bash <script.sh>
```

you open a new subshell inside of your session. This subshell is not the same than your shell where you run the script and all the commands inside the script runs in this new subshell.

if you want execute the script on the environment of your shell try this:

```
source <script.sh>
```

Bye

Comment: That did not work. I still have problems to change directories.